# Put large text into DB2 table in php

Tags: php, db2

I've got a table with Clob field (is there any other data types in IBM DB2 to store text in it?). So, i have an article (html+css+text). I used `htmlspecialchars($text)` to prepare the text.

Then I do next thing:

```
$query="update tbl_lang_text set text='$text' where ownerid=$id and lang like '$lng'  and type=1";
$stmt = db2_prepare($this->conn, $query);
$result = db2_execute($stmt);
```

So i got an error. something like: the query is too big. So. how can i update my field with such a large text?

P.S.: An test article contains 28 154 characters with spaces.

Comment: What platform is your DB2 database? iSeries, Windows, Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CLOB column can take up to 2 147 483 647 characters, so it is unlikely that this is what is causing the error.

What could be problem (and even if it's not you should fix it), is that you are not escaping the input at all. Using prepared statements (i.e.: `db2_prepare`) is good, but you still need to use parameters and values to have your data escaped:

```
$query = "update tbl_lang_text set text=?".
         "where ownerid=? and lang like ? and type=1";
$stmt = db2_prepare($this->conn, $query);
$result = db2_execute($stmt, array($text, $id, $lng));
```

It is very likely that `$text` contains at least an apostrophe `'` and that your query fails because of it.